# window.open does not work in javascript function

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am trying to open different pages depending upon the user who has logged in. The code works fine till setting the session storage variables and can get the variables but the function window.open does not work after that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Greenleaf Airconditioning Services LLC</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100,300,400,600,700,100italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

<h2 style="color:green;" class="text-center">Green Leaf Airconditioning Services LLC</h2>    

<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="register-form" role="form" onsubmit="getval()" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="empid">Emp ID:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="form-control" id="empid" required placeholder=1 required>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="psw">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">          
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="psw" required placeholder="Enter password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-8">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        <a href="register.html" class="btn btn-link" role="button">Register</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

    <!-- /.container -->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
function getval(){
    var myobj = {};
    myobj.usrname= $( "#empid" ).val();
    myobj.usrpass= $("#psw").val();

    var myjson = JSON.stringify(myobj);

    $.ajaxSetup( { "async": false } );
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "php/checkpass.php",
    data: {"points": myjson}
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {

        if(msg == 'Success') {
        // now set the session storage variables for this user for future actions
        // get json object of all the data related to the user except the password
        $.getJSON("php/sessionstore.php", {id: $( "#empid" ).val()}, function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {
          localStorage.setItem('userid', item.EmpId);        
          localStorage.setItem('username', item.EmpName);
          localStorage.setItem('usermail', item.EmpEmail);
          localStorage.setItem('supmail', item.SupEmail);
          localStorage.setItem('issup', item.IsSup); });    
        });
        } else
        {
            alert('incorrect password');
            $("#register-form").reset();
        }
    });
    $.ajaxSetup( { "async": true} );

    alert(localStorage.getItem("userid"));
    window.open ('http://www.airtec-intl.com/pages/hrmain.html','_self',false);
    if(localStorage.getItem("userid") > 0){
        // load pages depending upon login - normal users, supervisors, human resources
        if(localStorage.getItem("userid") > 999){
            window.open ('pages/hrmain.html','_self',false);
        } else if(localStorage.getItem("issup") > 0){
            window.open ('pages/supmain.html','_self',false);
        } else {
            window.open ('pages/empmain.html','_self',false);
        }
    }   
  return false;  
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I changed the code as mentioned in the answers below but no avail. The changed javascript below

```
function getval(){
    var myobj = {};
    myobj.usrname= $( "#empid" ).val();
    myobj.usrpass= $("#psw").val();

    var myjson = JSON.stringify(myobj);

    $.ajaxSetup( { "async": false } );
    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "php/checkpass.php",
    data: {"points": myjson}
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {

        if(msg == 'Success') {
        // now set the session storage variables for this user for future actions
        // get json object of all the data related to the user except the password
        $.getJSON("php/sessionstore.php", {id: $( "#empid" ).val()}, function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {
          localStorage.setItem('userid', item.EmpId);        
          localStorage.setItem('username', item.EmpName);
          localStorage.setItem('usermail', item.EmpEmail);
          localStorage.setItem('supmail', item.SupEmail);
          localStorage.setItem('issup', item.IsSup); });
          if(localStorage.getItem("userid") > 999){
            window.location.href='http://www.airtec-intl.com/pages/hrmain.html';
            } else if(localStorage.getItem("issup") > 0){
                window.location.href='http://www.airtec-intl.com/pages/supmain.html';
            } else {
                window.location.href='http://www.airtec-intl.com/pages/empmain.html';
           }

        });
        } else
        {
            alert('incorrect password');
            $("#register-form").reset();
        }
    });
    $.ajaxSetup( { "async": true} );

  return false;  
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by window.open *doesn't work*? What are you expecting and what is actually happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Can you check if you are having any popup blocker enabled in your browser. Also window.open may not be the best way if you want to `redirect` users to different page. In that case you may use something like `window.location = 'uri'` instead. Also check your developer tool console and see if there are any errors. `Command + Option + J` (Mac) or `Control + Shift + J`

Comment: I would like the page hrmain.html to open in the same window but that does not open. I see the value 1000 in the local storage, so the values are set but corresponding page does not open. Tks.

Comment: You may need to move the code for checking `localStorage` inside `.done` callback for your ajax call otherwise `localStorage` would be  checked before service call is actually made.

Comment: Yes, you may want to do 2 things:
1. Yes as @Abhas said, you won't be able to get the value from locationStorage if you run that synchronously, because the Ajax call is async as you specified. So move that code inside the `.done`
2. IF you want that to be open in the same window, then you should do `window.location.href="xxx"` instead of using window.open

Comment: Still does not solve the issue even when i make the changes mentioned above.

Comment: Is there a reason you have a space between `window.open` and the first paren?

Comment: sorry that would be a typo. i changed that. tks